# Alternative to frames and iframes in HTML

Tags: java, html, iframe, tags

I am trying to generate a html page dynamically in Java. The structure of the page is such that it will have two parts
 1. Menu - containing hyperlinks to open respective reports.
 2. Area to display the report based on the hyperlink clicked in menu.

I tried using "frameset" tag but I was unable to create the html page as per the above scenario.

Can someone please help me to solve this issue? I wanted to understand, is there any alternative to "frame" tag or how can this be achieved using "iframe" option?
Also, when I create the html page using "iframe" the page opens successfully in Internet Explorer but not in Mozilla Firefox. Can someone please point me in right direction to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using div tag These can be easily created dynamically.
Create 2 divisions using the div tag and then adjust them according to your need.
Divs can be easily populated dynamically.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail? Also, can you please edit your answer, I am not able to view what you have written after "Try using".

Comment: Do I need to use "iframe"  inside "div" tags or I just need to create two different "div" and align them in columns?

Comment: No need to use iframe inside div.

Comment: The two div tags that I am creating are such that one tag contains a table with each cell containing hyperlink and once a hyperlink is clicked I need to open its contents in the second div tag. 
Can you please explain how can this be achieved without using iframe and only div tags? I think to open the link in new div I need to use iframe, please correct me if I am mistaken. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use onclick instead of hyperlinks and invoke a function with the click to rewrite the innerHTML of the second div in which you want to show the dynamic data.